# filter a list with redux - react native

Tags: react-native, redux

I have the following code that filters by name on a searchbar.

```
state = {
    canchas,
    canchasFiltradas: [],
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.setState({canchasFiltradas: this.state.canchas})
  }

  buscarCanchas = (name) => {
    this.setState({
      canchasFiltradas: this.state.canchas.filter(cancha => {
        return cancha.name.indexOf(name) > -1
      })
    })
  }
```

Where canchas is referencing a json file. This is the searchbar component:

```
<SearchBar
    onChangeText={nombre =>  this.buscarCanchas(nombre)}
    onClearText={() => this.setState({canchas})}
/>
```

Now I added redux to the project and it doesnt work.
This is the reducer code:

```
const initialState = {
    canchas,
    canchasFiltradas: [],
};

const reducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case BUSCAR_CANCHA:
            return {
                ...state,
                canchas: state.canchas.filter(cancha => {
                    return cancha.name.indexOf(action.name) > -1
                })
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Comment: You'll need to be more specific than "doesn't work". There are a lot of things in your code that you haven't included in your post that could break this. A few things to note, though.. 1) this seems like a job for a selector, not a reducer, ie the filtering. 2) your reducer is setting the `canchas` property with the filtered list, not the `canchasFiltradas` property. 3) depending on how you've wired up your reducer it may not be getting the full state, but rather just the `canchas` slice of the state.

Comment: By "doesnt work" I mean it does search but deletes from screen all the other canchas that were filtered. https://youtu.be/3NHoyeuwWMM

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the original state value in your reducer. That's why it doesn't show everything when you clear the search. You should store the filtered data in `canchasFiltradas` instead of `canchas`.

See below:

```
const initialState = {
    canchas,
    canchasFiltradas: [],
};

const reducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case BUSCAR_CANCHA:
            return {
                ...state,
                canchasFiltradas: state.canchas.filter(cancha => {
                    return cancha.name.indexOf(action.name) > -1
                })
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```